# Java Socket: receiving wrong boolean

Tags: java, sockets

I have a client/server architecture that sends class-instances via sockets.

In one class I have a boolean:

```
public class Survey implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1156493488498723461L;
    private boolean isExpired;

    public Survey() {
        this.isExpired = false;
    }

    public void markAsExpired() {
        this.isExpired = true;
    }

    public boolean isExpired() {
        return isExpired;
    }
}
```

The part where I send the packet:

```
survey.markAsExpired();
HashMap<Header, Object> packet = new HashMap<Header, Object>();
packet.put(header, survey);

System.out.println(survey.isExpired()); // prints true
try {
    socketOutput.writeObject(packet);
    socketOutput.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I send that class with the boolean set to true (see above), the client always receives it as false.

Where does this come from?

Comment: Can you share the code that creates the instance and sends it through the socket?

Comment: @BackSlash Done.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? A full yet minimal program that we can run.

Comment: @JohnKugelman also with the full socket overhead?

Comment: See if you can reproduce the bug without sockets. What if you just hook up an `ObjectOutputStream` to an `ObjectInputStream` in the same program?

Comment: Where is client code ?

Comment: very strange, just wrote a test program using above code and it worked fine (without need of deep copy)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by sending a deep copy instead of the object itself. Workaround but worked.